# Linux ping is routed correctly and then dropped

Tags: linux, routing

I have two routers that are connected via Wireguard.  Access to the internet via wg works fine, but I would like to access my PI attached to routerS.

From routerS, I can happily ping the locally attached PI (**OutputInfo** line below).  An identical ping from RouterT (**FwdInfo** line below) is received by routerS and seems ready to FORWARD to the correct **OUT=br-lan** interface, but instead routerT replies with ICMP TYPE=3 CODE=3 (FailInfo line below)

```
routerS kernel: [95228.293520] OutputInfo IN=    OUT=br-lan      SRC=192.168.0.1     DST=192.168.0.80 LEN=978 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=28681 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=29579 SEQ=0 okPingFromRouterS    
routerS kernel: [37413.743406] FwdInfo    IN=wg0 OUT=br-lan MAC= SRC=192.168.219.246 DST=192.168.0.80 LEN=978 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=5115  DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=14595 SEQ=0 failedPingFromRouterT    
routerS kernel: [37413.758681] FailInfo   IN= OUT=wg0            SRC=192.168.219.247 DST=192.168.219.246 LEN=576 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=64 ID=21316 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=3 CODE=3 [SRC=192.168.219.246 DST=192.168.0.80 LEN=978 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=5115 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=14595 SEQ=0 ]   FailureResponseMessage
# packet logging from iptables
```

Routing appears to be straight forward, but clearly I am missing something.  There is a separate routing table (200) for packets originating from br-lan, but I think that should not matter here.

```
root@routerS:~# ip route
default via 192.168.8.1 dev eth0.2 proto static src 192.168.8.84
192.168.0.0/24 dev br-lan proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.1
192.168.8.0/24 dev eth0.2 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.8.84
192.168.219.246/31 dev wg0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.219.247

root@routerS:~# ip rule
0:      from all lookup local
1:      from all iif br-lan lookup 200
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default

root@routerS:~# ip route show table 200
default dev wg0 proto static scope link
```

Why is the forwarded ping not being forwarded to the PI?

Comment: Do you have IP forwarding enabled in kernel?

Comment: Yes.  Forwarding is enabled